# Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app. Tried numerous different things posted on this site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

Keep receiving the following error when trying to push to heroku.  This is literally copy and pasted from the instructor.  I really don't know what else to try.  Any suggestions?
These are the extra details that I am adding to post this question, because apparently I need to write a book regarding the details of this post

```
 remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    remote: npm ERR! errno 2
    remote: npm ERR! expensify@1.0.0 build:prod: `webpack -p --env production`
    remote: npm ERR! Exit status 2
    remote: npm ERR!
    remote: npm ERR! Failed at the expensify@1.0.0 build:prod script.
    remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    remote:
    remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.cjxoG/_logs/2018-09-19T01_45_36_828Z-debug.log
    remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    remote: npm ERR! errno 2
    remote: npm ERR! expensify@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm run build:prod`
    remote: npm ERR! Exit status 2
    remote: npm ERR!
    remote: npm ERR! Failed at the expensify@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
    remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    remote:
    remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.cjxoG/_logs/2018-09-19T01_45_36_842Z-debug.log
    remote:
    remote: -----> Build failed
    remote:
    remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
    remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
    remote:
    remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
    remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
    remote:
    remote:        Love,
    remote:        Heroku
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:
    remote: !       Push rejected to expensebudget.
    remote:
    To https://git.heroku.com/expensebudget.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/expensebudget.git'
```

This is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "expensify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Andrew Mead",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p --env production",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "jest --config=jest.config.json",
    "start": "server/server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build:prod"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "express": "4.15.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "normalize.css": "7.0.0",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "15.6.0",
    "react-dates": "12.3.0",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-modal": "2.2.2",
    "react-redux": "5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "4.1.2",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "uuid": "3.1.0",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "2.9.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "1.5.1",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.5.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"build:prod": "webpack -p --env.production"
```

instead of

```
"build:prod": "webpack -p --env production"
```

Comment: did you "npm install"

Comment: Yes, I did this as well.

Comment: "npm cache clean --force" , 
than delete node_modules folder , 
then delete package-lock.json file, 
"npm install"

Answer (score 0):

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then delete node_modules folder

then delete package-lock.json file

```
npm install
```